# Can't see any tables in DataGrip with XAMPP

Tags: sql, linux, mariadb, xampp, datagrip

I'm trying to connect DataGrip to my local MariaDB database launched with XAMPP, but I don't see any tables. So I can't run any requests, which are work in PMA. What can i do with that?

[I have tables in PHPMyAdmin...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e00Mw.png)[...but have not in DataGrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnGcp.png)

I tried to reinstall DataGrip and XAMPP, but it not solved my problem

Comment: Have you tried to click refresh in "Database Explorer"? Do you connect with user that have proper rights? Also please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") if there are any related errors/warning.

Comment: Andrei, have you tried to specify database in your data source general tab?